# Error connecting Django to MSSQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, django, python-3.x

Am getting an error in making migrations for my current django project.

below is the code written in settings.py file to connect to MSSQL Server.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE':'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME':'JTPROD',
    'HOST':'TZACL5X8H1N2\SQLEXPRESS', ##this is my local machine database
    'USER':'xxx', ##ommitted for the post 
    'PASSWORD':'xxx',##ommitted for tht post
    'PORT':'',

    'OPTIONS':{
        'provider': 'SQLOLEDB', # Have also tried 'SQLCLI11' and 'SQLCLI10'
        'extra_params': 'DataTypeCompatibility=80',
        'driver':'SQL Server',
             },
    },
}
```

**but am getting the following error when I run "python manage.py migrate**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
>   line 216, in ensure_connection
>       self.connect()   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
>   line 194, in connect
>       self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py",
>   line 307, in get_new_connection
>       timeout=timeout) pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword
>   supplied (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 15, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 375, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 316, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 353, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 83, in wrapped
>       res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py",
>   line 82, in handle
>       executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)   File
>   "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
>   line 18, in **init**
>       self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py",
>   line 49, in **init**
>       self.build_graph()   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py",
>   line 212, in build_graph
>       self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py",
>   line 61, in applied_migrations
>       if self.has_table():   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py",
>   line 44, in has_table
>       return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
>   File
>   "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
>   line 255, in cursor
>       return self._cursor()   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
>   line 232, in _cursor
>       self.ensure_connection()   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
>   line 216, in ensure_connection
>       self.connect()   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
>   line 89, in **exit**
>       raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
>   line 216, in ensure_connection
>       self.connect()   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
>   line 194, in connect
>       self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)   File "C:\Users\elukamis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py",
>   line 307, in get_new_connection
>       timeout=timeout) django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Neither DSN nor SERVER
>   keyword supplied (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')

**Does anyone have an idea on what I might be missing in my configuration ?**

Comment: Your `'HOST'` key contains a backslash: `'TZACL5X8H1N2\SQLEXPRESS'`, what if you use a *raw string literal*? `r'TZACL5X8H1N2\SQLEXPRESS'`.

Comment: Thanks, just tried your suggestion but am getting the same error

Comment: The backslash I have put is for 'server\instance'

Comment: `server\instance` is for explicitly named (intentionally chosen as "named instance" type of installation) instances only. `default` instance cannot be accessed in this way. Try removing `\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: Still getting the same error even after removing \SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/232

Comment: The solution showed there is not the syntax normally used in the setting.py file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking for an answer, I'm not sure this will help you, but it helped me when I was getting a similar error.  SQL Server Express has TCP/IP connections disabled by default, but they apparently need to be enabled in order to allow a connection like this.

Open SQL Server Configuration Manager, expand 'SQL Server Network Configuration', and click on 'Protocols for SQLEXPRESS'.  Assuming the entry for TCP/IP shows as Disabled, right-click that and select Properties.  On the 'Protocol' tab, set Enabled to Yes.  I also updated the 'IP Addresses' tab by entering '1433' into the TCP Port field of the 'IPAll' section (at the bottom).  Then I specified `'PORT':'1433',` in the settings.py DATABASES configuration section.  I'm not sure that was necessary, but following those steps allowed my app to successfully connect to SQL Server Express.